# How to validate empty text in spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner

For my spinner I have a hidden text and a validation code to display error message if spinner is skipped. While the code works if the spinner is not selected, the error message gets displayed all the time even if I have selected an option in spinner.

```
  final int pos = spinner5.getSelectedItemPosition();
  boolean failflag = false;

  String name = null;
  if (pos!=0) {
  } else {
      failflag = true;
      TextView errorText = (TextView)spinner6.getSelectedView();
      errorText.setError("");
      errorText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
      errorText.setText("Enter your Marital Status");
  }
```

Comment: Where do you use that code? In a ClickListener?

Comment: in button click @JuanCruzSoler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ...

```
spinner6.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView errorText = (TextView)spinner6.getSelectedView();
        if (position > 0) { 
            errorText.setText("");
        }else{
           failflag = true; 
           errorText.setError("");
           errorText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
           errorText.setText("Enter your Marital Status");
        }     
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in a condition before setting the error.

Something like (pseudocode below):

```
If (textview.text = invalid) {
textview.setError(Please put valid text) 
} else {
textview.setError(null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set an `OnItemSelectedListener` in your spinner to hide the error once a value is selected:

```
spinner5.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position != 0) {
            TextView errorText = (TextView)spinner6.getSelectedView();
            errorText.setText("");
        }        
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```